# Getting references to views in ListView

Tags: android, listview, reference, get, visibility

I''m struggling a little with the hierarchy here. I'd like to get references to every ImageButton view with the id delete_img in my listView. The imagebutton is added via the XML in the row layout xml.

Essentially i want to be able to set the visibility of a certain element within every row but i cant figure out how to get that sort of reference. Is there an alternative way of doing this? The method deleteShow() is my attempt to get at it so far but its obviously wrong as i am getting a Null Pointer when trying to set the Visibility.

**NotesFragment**

```
public class NotesFragment extends ListFragment {

private CommentsDataSource datasource;
private View v = null;



public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Cursor theNotes = (Cursor) returnNotes();
    String[] projection = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENT,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_COMMENTNAME,
            MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_FOLDERFK };
    int[] to = new int[] { R.id.id_txt, R.id.content_txt, R.id.title_text };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.notes_list_layout, theNotes, projection, to);
    setListAdapter(sca);

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notesfragment, container, false);
    deleteShow();

    return v;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    Intent intentView = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            ViewNote.class);
    intentView.putExtra("id", id);

    startActivity(intentView);
}

public Cursor returnNotes() {
    Cursor theNotesCursor = null;
    datasource = new CommentsDataSource(getActivity());
    datasource.open();
    theNotesCursor = datasource.getAllCommentsAsCursor();
    return theNotesCursor;
}

public void deleteShow() {
    ImageButton b = (ImageButton) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.delete_img);
    b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}



public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    datasource.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hierarchy for dealing with `ListView` is not that complicated once you understand what's going on. Think of the `ListView` as the framwork that holds a bunch of child views or Items. Those Items each have child views that consist of the individual elements that make up a row in the `ListView`. To modify a list `Item` you either need to (1) change the data backing that item and update your `ArrayAdapter` or (2) find the individual `Item` you are trying to modify from within the `ListView` and then act on the child views for that individual item.

The easiest way to do this is to modify the data in the adapter backing the list and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `ArrayAdapter` to update the `ListView`. I don't know how your adapter is set up so to give you direct advice is difficult but the general idea is that you want to change the data backing the `Item` you want to modify, change that data, and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ArrayAdapter` so that the `ListView` reflects the changes.

To modify an individual item directly is much more complicated. You cannot do it in one step as your code proposes - finding the individual view by id and then changing its visibility - will not operate accross the entire list as you suspect. `findViewById` is likley returning `null` because it is not looking within an indvidual list element but within the whole list - i.e. the outer list structure - for a view that is not there.

To do what you want programatically you need to (1) get a reference to the `ListView` itself; (2) find the first displayed view within the list by calling `getFirstVisiblePosition()`; (3) figure out how far down from that first visibile item is the item you want to modify; (4) get that item; (5) modify it

This ends up just being a pain in the ass. Its much easier to modify the data backing the list and update than to find single view.

Comment: Okay, I kind of suspected this. Let me get this straight. As far as i understand it is not possible to get a reference to every element in the list rows that has the id (suchandsuch) and getting each element individually and doing it sounds like a nightmare due to the way listView works. 


Theoretically, since my current button is an XML element. Could i remove it from the XML, add it back into every list row generated programatically with references to be used when i need to make them appear/disappear later?

Comment: If you list is of a fixed length maybe. Assuming you could get a reference to those buttons properly you would need to maintain a seperate list to just keep track of those references. What is the case that is triggering their removal? Maybe I can suggest an easier way?

Comment: The button exists after a set of text views in each row. Essentially it is a delete button that would allow the user to delete the information associated with that row. I want to be able to show/hide the delete buttons at will since i don't want users accidentally clicking the delete buttons. (plus it just looks bad).

Comment: Like on swipe in the iOS platform? I cant think of an easy way to make that happen. The problem is that the button is necessarily within an item within the list. A global delete item does not sound like it would work. That would be much easier since you could get the item onClick and remove it from the list easily. To delete individual TextView's you're going to have to do it the hard way.

Comment: Yes similar to iOS. Essentially I'd like to hide the delete buttons so the user cannot click them. I'm surprised that there is no obvious way to do this. The delete button finds and takes and ID field textview that is invisible in the listView (because i couldnt find a better way to do it) and then removes it from the database. 

All id like to do is make it possible to hide the delete buttons given a certain command. If there is no easy way to do this ill accept your answer and close the question.

Comment: Well you can do it its just not and "easy" solution. You certainly can use a gesture listener and or onClick to do that action but its not a simple fix from the code you have.